# Second-order energies of a quartic pertubation of a harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory, anharmonic-oscillators

A homework exercise was to calculate the second-order [perturbation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)) of a quantum anharmonic oscillator with the potential

$$
V(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \lambda x^4.
$$

We set $\hbar = 1$, $m=1$, etc. Using the harmonic oscillator $H = \frac{1}{2}p^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2$ as my basis hamiltonian, I calculated the perturbed ground state energy multiplication factors as

$$
E_0(\lambda) = 1 + \frac{3}{4} \lambda - \frac{21}{\color{red}{8}} \lambda^2 + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^3)
$$

while our lecture notes state

$$
E_0(\lambda) = 1 + \frac{3}{4} \lambda - \frac{21}{\color{red}{16}} \lambda^2 + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^3).
$$

I did not find any sources in literature, neither did I find a mistake in my calculations yet. Which one is correct?

Comment: Your lecture notes formula is correct, see this [paper](http://www.jurp.org/2012/MS134.pdf), formulae $10$ page $6$ (see also formulae $6$ page $4$)

Comment: I think this is the source where our professor copied the results. A colleage just pointed me to [this paper](http://re.vu/doc-download/rsmith314/284761/work_example-robert.smith-mathseniorseminarpaperfinal.244640.1376625401.pdf), see forumla 20, which has the correct values. Or are they doing the same mistake as I did? (You have to right-click, select "Save as..." and open the PDF, their webserver is misconfigured.) Found [another one](http://www.physics.buffalo.edu/gonsalves/aqm/lectures/07/lec-07.pdf). See page 7. Are they both wrong?

Comment: The non perturbed hamiltonian is different. In the reference I gave, it was $H=- \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + x^2 + \lambda x^4$ (see formula $2$ page $3$). So, this convention is different from yours, so it can explain the difference.

Comment: Hi Trimok & iblue: Dec 12th, 2022. 404 Links now dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your result is not correct (with your convention for the hamiltonian):

Starting from your hamiltonian $H = \frac{1}{2}p^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \lambda x^4$, and with :

$$E_0^{(1)} = V_{00}, \quad E_0^{(2)} = \sum\limits_{m \neq 0} \frac{|V_{0m}|^2}{E_0-E_m} \tag{1}$$

Here : $E_n^{(0)} = n + \frac{1}{2}$, with $V_{00} = \lambda \langle 0|X^4|0\rangle$ and  $|V_{0m}|^2 = \lambda^2 |\langle 0|X^4|m\rangle|^2$, and with $X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (a+a^+), P = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(a^+-a)$

By applying successively ($4$ times) the operator $X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (a+a^+)$, on the state $|0\rangle$ (with the rules $a|n\rangle = \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle$ and $a^+|n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$)  you find :

$X^4|0\rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}^4}(\sqrt{24}|4\rangle + 2\sqrt{18}|2\rangle + 3|0\rangle) \tag{2}$

So, finally :

$$E_0^{(1)} = \frac{3}{4} \lambda\tag{3}$$

$$E_0^{(2)} = -\frac{1}{2^4}(\frac{24}{4} + \frac{4*18}{2})\lambda^2= - \frac{42}{16} {\lambda^2} = - \frac{21}{8}\tag{4} {\lambda^2}$$

So, finally, the (absolute) modifyed energy for the ground state is  :

$$E_0(\lambda) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4} \lambda - \frac{21}{8} {\lambda^2} \tag{5}$$

This is compatible with the other convention for the hamiltonian (in my [reference](http://www.jurp.org/2012/MS134.pdf)) which is :

$H' = p^2 + x^2 + \lambda x^4 = 2(\frac{1}{2}p^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2} x^4)$, the (absolute) modifyed energy for the ground state is then :

$E'_0(\lambda) = 2 E_0(\frac{\lambda}{2}) = 2(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4} \frac{\lambda}{2} - \frac{21}{8} \frac{{\lambda^2}}{4})=1 + \frac{3}{4} \lambda - \frac{21}{16} {\lambda^2} \tag{6}$

Now, if you want relative factors, you have to consider $\frac{E_0(\lambda)}{E_0(0)}$ or $\frac{E'_0(\lambda)}{E'_0(0)}$, depending on the hamiltonian you are considering, so with your hamiltonian $H$, you have :

$$\frac{E_0(\lambda)}{E_0(0)} = 1+ \frac{3}{2} \lambda - \frac{21}{4} {\lambda^2} \tag{7}$$
while, with the hamiltonian $H'$, we get :

$$\frac{E'_0(\lambda)}{E'_0(0)}=1 + \frac{3}{4} \lambda - \frac{21}{16} {\lambda^2}\tag{8}$$

Answer (score 3):

I did this both by hand, and using Mathematica, and obtained the same result you obtained for the second order correction term.  Here's my work.

Write $\hat x$ in terms of creation and annihilation operators;
\begin{align}
  \hat x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat a+\hat a^\dagger).
\end{align}
Recall what they do to energy eigenstates;
\begin{align}
  a^\dagger|n\rangle =\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle, \qquad a|n\rangle = \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle. 
\end{align}
use these relations to show that
\begin{align}
  \hat x^4|0\rangle &= \frac{1}{4}(3|0\rangle + 6\sqrt{2}|2\rangle + 2\sqrt{6}|4\rangle)
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
  E_0^{(2)} 
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{|\langle m|\lambda \hat x^4|0\rangle|^2}{(0+\frac{1}{2})-(m+\frac{1}{2})}
=-\frac{\lambda^2}{16}\left(\frac{(6\sqrt{2})^2}{2}+\frac{(2\sqrt{6})^2}{4}\right)
= -\frac{21}{8}\lambda^2
\end{align}

However, as Trimok points out, your zeroth order term should be a $1/2$, which changes the overall normalization of the answer.